# Issues reading in '*' character in Python into a new string

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, comments, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to remove multi-line SQL comments in a SQL text and execute the remaining statements. The result should be a new string that leaves out all of the multi-line SQL comments.

However, when reading in the `'*'` character from the `SELECT` statement, it's making the printed output string incorrect. Logically, this doesn't make any sense. Wondering if there are any known Python bugs with this character?

```
#sql = "actual sql code goes here; \n /*comment #1*/ more sql code would go 
#here; \n more renditions of SQL code here; \n /*comment #2*/ SELECT*FROM 
#TABLE;"

sql = "SELECT* FROM TABLE a WHERE THIS TRUE"

sql_2 = ""
flag = True

try:

    for index, character in enumerate(sql):
        while (flag):
            if character != r'/' and sql[index + 1] != r'*':
                sql_2 += character
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                flag = False

        if (character == r'*' and sql[index + 1] == r'/'):
            flag = True

        elif (character == r'/' and sql[index - 1] == r'*'):
            flag = True

except IndexError:
    if character != r'/':
        sql_2 += character

print(sql_2)
```

Expected Output: `'SELECT* FROM TABLE a WHERE THIS TRUE'`

Actual Output: `'SELEC'`

Comment: you'd better do that with `re` (regex) module

Comment: I suspect that the indentation of the second if-elif statement is incorrect. It is _not_ in the while loop.

Comment: @DYZ, you are correct, that was a mistake when I tried copying over the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

sql = "actual sql code goes here; \n /*comment #1*/ more sql code would go here; \n more renditions of SQL code here; \n /*comment #2*/ SELECT*FROM TABLE;"

re.sub(r'/[*].*[*]/', '', sql)

# Output =>
# 'actual sql code goes here; \n  more sql code would go here; \n more renditions of SQL code here; \n  SELECT*FROM TABLE;'
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much @mVChr. We had worked with regular expressions for about a half hour today, but could not come up with that one. It worked. Thank you very much!